# Handle erroneously ASCII-encoded non-breaking space in UTF-8 file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a Python 2.7 script which imports data from CSV files exported from various others sources.

As part of the import process I have a small function that establishes the correct character encoding for the file. I then open the file and loop the lines using:

```
with io.open(filename, "r", encoding=file_encoding) as input_file:
    for raw_line in input_file:
        cleaned_line = raw_line.replace('\x00', '').replace(u"\ufeff", "").encode('utf-8')
        # do stuff
```

The files from this source usually come as UTF-8 (with BOM) and I detect the encoding 'utf-8-sig' and use that to open the file.

The problem I am having is that one of my data sources returns a file that seems to have an encoding error. The rest of the file (about 27k lines of CSV data) are all correct, as usual, but one line fails.

The line in question fails with this error (at the `for raw_line in input_file` line):

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 1709: invalid start byte

The line has several non-breaking spaces characters that are encoded as with a single byte with value 'A0' rather than 2 bytes with 'C2 A0'.

I am already doing some light cleaning on a line by line basis for other problems as you can see on my "cleaned_line" line at the top of the loop (I dislike doing this per line but with the files I get I haven't found a way to do it better). However, the code fails before I ever even get there.

Is there a correct/nice way to handle this particular issue? I thought I'd nailed the whole encoding issue until this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell Python to ignore decoding errors, or to replace the faulty bytes with a placeholder character.

Set `errors` to `'ignore'` to ignore the `A0` bytes:

```
with io.open(filename, "r", encoding=file_encoding, errors='ignore') as input_file:
```

or to `'replace'` to replace them with the [U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](http://codepoints.net/U+fffd):

```
with io.open(filename, "r", encoding=file_encoding, errors='replace') as input_file:
```

UTF-8 is a self-correcting encoding; bytes are either always part of a multi-byte code point, or can be decoded as ASCII directly, so ignoring un-decodable bytes is relatively safe.

Comment: Thank you! I have never before found that parameter useful and it totally didn't come to mind to try it. It did the trick, and as the character is out side of the data I save, it does not matter if it did drop stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can do encoding 'translit/long' to normalize utf-8 to table of string charts, need to import translitcodec first.